# Wheel spoke reflector Flectr

Tags: safety, protection

Winter is comming, days become shorter, need extra visibility for darker times.

Have somebody used Flectr zero reflector (https://shop.flectr.bike/collections/reflective-products)?
Is it worth the money?

I can't find any decent review of it.

Thanks

Comment: There's a review here: http://road.cc/content/review/228444-flectr-zero-aero-wheel-reflectors

Comment: They seem expensive (€15) when you could cut your own out of < €1 of 3M diamond grade reflective tape

Comment: Reflectors are there to reflect the light from car a headlight beam. The benefit of better reflectors quickly gets into diminishing returns. Better to spend the money on reflectors on backpacks/clothing/ankle straps - more is better. (Notice the difference between a cyclist wearing a white shirt vs black)

Comment: I agree with @mattnz. Wheel reflectors like these only really help when you're broadside to a car. If you want wheel reflectors with side visibility, and you've got deep-ish rim sections, lay reflective dots between spokes on half the rim, which will create a more pronounced strobing effect, and doesn't festoon your bike with fluttering crap so much.

Answer (score 3):

No I've not used those specific ones.  However I have used spoke-mounted clip-on reflectors, and consider them far superior to the traditional yellow plastic blobs that adorn many new bikes.

Reflectors on the wheel make your bike much more visible from the side.  Lights are generally not set up to point sideways, and they have relatively little leakage to the sides.

Reflective sidewall tyres are okay, but they're a continuous band and don't have the same movement that revolving spoke protectors have.

**Answer:  Sound concept and good idea**

Pricing?  That is for you to decide and we don't really do prices here because the website is global.  On looking at the website, they seem to be stickers made of reflective material, similar to whats on a roadcone.  Your local craft shop or safety department in a hardware shop probably has rolls of similar reflector tape.

Comment: [I bought these](http://www.dx.com/p/bike-wheel-spoke-abs-safety-reflective-tube-reflector-grey-12-pcs-228130#.WgBKp7zXZhE) and they've lasted multiple years.

Comment: I've got similar ones and can vouch for their visibililty as I walk towards the bike with a (head)torch.  I've got some others on the trailer where the retro-reflective layer is stuck on.  They're less good as the layer peels off (but can then be used as a retroreflective sticker so it's not all bad).  In my case they're in addition to the old-fashioned sort, reflective sidewalls and valve-cap lights

Comment: Another vote for the ones @Criggie linked. They lasted a couple of winters and, with enough of them, they appear as a wide reflective ring on the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Bought them as double-set for under 14 euro (https://shop.flectr.bike/collections/reflective-products/products/flectr-zero-double-pack). Look nice.

Can´t understand why people ruin their bikes with diy parts....
[image: wheel reflector diy-style.... wonderful :-)]

Best
Jo